# Algorithm for Converting Non-balanced Base-n to Balanced Base-n (for odd n)

Tags: binary, number-systems

Let $n \in 2 \mathbb{N} - 1$. I was wondering what sort of algorithms there are for converting (non-balanced) base-n to balanced base-n, where "balanced" is as is described in this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed-digit_representation, and where the representation is as short as possible (for example, $7 = (1,1,1)_2$ with lower powers of the base being toward the right); in other words, base n with minimal residues for digits.  For such a balanced ternary, two algorithms are given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary#Conversion_from_ternary.

Thank you for any help that you might give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an "ordinary" base-$n$ representation using digits $0,\ldots,n-1,$
a number $x$ with $k+1$ digits and no negative sign will have a leading digit $d$ 
(a $d$ in the "$n^k$" place) under exactly the following conditions:

$$ 0 \leq x - dn^k < n^k.$$

The greatest possible value of a number of $k+1$ digits is

$$ (n-1)n^k + (n-1)n^{k-1} + \cdots + (n-1)n^2 + (n-1)n + (n-1) = n^{k+1} - 1.$$

For a balanced base-$n$ representation where $n$ is odd,
a number $x$ with $(k+1)$ digits will have a leading digit $d$ when

$$ -\frac{n^k}{2} < x - dn^k < \frac{n^k}{2}.$$

In this case there is no possibility of equality, since $x - dn^k$ is
an integer and $\frac{n^k}{2}$ is not.
The greatest possible value of a number of $k+1$ digits is

$$ \frac{n-1}{2}n^k + \frac{n-1}{2}n^{k-1} + \cdots +
 \frac{n-1}{2}n^2 + \frac{n-1}{2}n + \frac{n-1}{2} = \frac{n^{k+1} - 1}{2}$$

and similarly the least possible value is $-\frac{n^{k+1} - 1}{2}.$

For any odd $n,$ then, you can convert an ordinary base-$n$ number
whose digits are $c_p\cdots c_2c_1c_0$
to a balanced base-$n$ number whose digits are $d_q\cdots d_2d_1d_0$
by working from right to left, much like the way you would convert ordinary ternary
to balanced ternary.
That is, if you have already converted the rightmost $k$ digits of a number $x$,
you will have
$$ x = (c_p\cdots c_{k+1}c'_k)n^k + (d_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0) $$
where $-\frac{n^k}{2} < d_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0 < \frac{n^k}{2}$
and $c'_k$ is either the original $c_k$ or $c_k + 1.$
(The number $d_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0$ will be negative if its most significant
non-zero digit is negative; it is possible for this number to have some leading zeros.)

Now write the number $x$ this way:
$$x = (c_p\cdots c_{k+2})n^{k+2} + c_{k+1}n^{k+1} + c_kn^k + (d_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0).$$
If $c_k < \frac n2,$ then 
$c_kn^k + (d_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0) < \frac{n^{k+1}}{2}$,
so you can set $d_k = c_k$ and write
$$ x = (c_p\cdots c_{k+1})n^{k+1} + (d_kd_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0). $$
If $c_k > \frac n2,$ then 
$c_kn^k + (d_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0) > \frac{n^{k+1}}{2}$,
so you will need to set $d_k = c_k - n$ so that you can write
$$\begin{eqnarray}
 x &=& (c_p\cdots c_{k+2})n^{k+2} + (c_{k+1}+1)n^{k+1} + (d_kd_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0)\\
&=& (c_p\cdots c_{k+2}c'_{k+1})n^{k+1} + (d_kd_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0)
\end{eqnarray}$$
where $c'_{k+1} = c_{k+1} + 1.$
That is, if you would "round up" from $c_k$ then you "carry $1$" to $c_{k+1}.$

For the rightmost digit, $c_0,$ of course, there are no digits to the right of it,
so $c'_0=c_0$ and you can omit $d_{k-1}\cdots d_1d_0$ 
when you apply the formulas above.
For the leftmost digit, $c_p,$ there is no digit $c_{p+1}$ to "carry" to, so
if $c_p > \frac n2$
you simply set $d_p = c_p - n$ and $d_{p+1} = 1$ and you're done.