# Can any integer be expressed as sums of powers of three?

Tags: summation, exponentiation

I heard a long time ago that any integer can be expressed as sums (or differences) of powers of three, using each power only once. Examples:

$5=9-3-1$

$6=9-3$

$22=27-9+3+1$

etc.

To my surprise, I couldn't find anything about this on the Internet. So..

1. Is this true? (So far I couldn't find any integer I can't express like this)
2. Is there a proof to it?
3. (Kind of a side question, assuming this is true): Is there a formula that gives the coefficients (-1, 0 or 1) for each power for a given integer?

Thanks

Comment: It is well-known: this system of representation is called [*balanced ternary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary).

Comment: I knew it had a fancy name and that's why I can't find it! Thanks. I would still like an explanation why this happens, though. Does it happen with numbers other than three?

Comment: You’re welcome. Not with coefficients of $-1,0$, and $1$, but in general it happens with powers of $2n+1$ with coefficients of $0,\pm1,\ldots,\pm n$.

Comment: Wow. That one seems harder to prove.. There must be a proof to this though, right? Anyway, you can post this as an answer if you want and I will accept. But I would still appreciate a proof :) Thanks

Comment: Balanced representations are discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078382/algorithm-for-converting-non-balanced-base-n-to-balanced-base-n-for-odd-n where you'll also find links to other sources. Here's a post about balanced base seven: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137608/conversion-from-decimal-to-special-number-system

Comment: @wololoo: Done! I also added Gerry Myerson’s link, which has some of the theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This system is well-known and is called [*balanced ternary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary). It generalizes to all odd bases, but instead of the digits $-1,0$, and $1$, for base $2n+1$ you have the digits $0,\pm 1,\ldots,\pm n$; you can read a bit more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed-digit_representation#Balanced_form_representations) (with further generalizations in the rest of that article) and in [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078382/algorithm-for-converting-non-balanced-base-n-to-balanced-base-n-for-odd-n).